# How to Auto Wire Property Value in resource class

Tags: spring, properties, dependency-injection

I am trying to auto wire property value into Resource class, when I start the server, value is setting for the property, when I ran my application the value is becoming zero.

my Resource Class:

```
private int maxAge;

    @Value("${max_age}")
    public void setMaxAge(int maxAge) {
        this.maxAge = maxAge;
    }
```

Context.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myWebApplication/test.properties" />
<bean id="resource" class="RestResource">
    <property name="maxAge" value="${max_age}"></property>
  </bean>
```

and I am using jersey-spring3 jar

Can some one please let me know what's wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Value("${max_age}")` and you would be fine!

Comment: That's not working, it is setting the value and the time of server start, I am seeing that value as null when I am running my application